# Apache Avro does not print BigDecimal into parquet file Error : java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.nio.ByteBuffer

Tags: java, parquet, avro, classcastexception

I need to create parquet file with using apache-avro library in Java8. the POJO created automatically from ".avsc" file with maven generation-resource. but I have trouble with BigDecimal fields in the file. I researched apache-avro library documentation([apache-avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/specification/_print/#decimal)).
I was able to created successfully POJO with the field types that I need. but I got exception while write phase. I saw similar problems that already asked but there is no solution to solve my problem.

here is the code that I'm working on [github code](https://github.com/hakanguneser/avro-example)

Employee_schema.avsc

```
{"type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.avro.example",
  "name": "Employee",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "name","type": "string"},
    {"name": "email","type": "string"},
    {"name": "salary",
      "type": { "type": "bytes",
                "logicalType": "decimal",
                "precision": 4,
                "scale": 2
      }}]
}
```

Main.class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File outputParquet = new File("./output.parquet");
    Files.deleteIfExists(outputParquet.toPath());
    Employee employee = new Employee("john", "john.doe@mail.com",BigDecimal.TEN);
    ParquetWriter<Employee> writer = AvroParquetWriter.<Employee>builder(new Path(outputParquet.getAbsolutePath()))
            .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
            .withSchema(employee.getSchema())
            .build();
    try {
        writer.write(employee);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.avro.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
            <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                            <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
                            <fieldVisibility>private</fieldVisibility>
                            <stringType>String</stringType>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Well, look at your employee class that was generated. What are its constructor parameters? Avro binary type could represent anything, not always a number. Since you're using just `TEN`, why not use double type?

Comment: ``TEN`` was just an example, the client I'm working with wants this as a decimal type field. So I'm looking for some general solutions to do this. Also, apache-avro already has a decimal type in its documentation, I want to figure out why I can't use it.

Comment: You can use it, but it'll generate a class with a ByteBuffer. No where have you told Avro anything about BigDecimal numeric type, such as `java-class` attribute. (unrelated, but you should remove hadoop-core dependency since it's very old and parquet already pulls in the correct one)